# Encoding issue of AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, xml, cordova, apk

I'm building phonegap app using phonegap-build.

I need to make some changes to the manifest of the android apk.

After i download the apk of my phonegap build, i rename it to .zip file to see the contents of the file.

When i open it, there i see the xml file there, and when i open that one, it has encoding problem.

This is what i see:

[image]

I understand it's a binary, but i need to see the content in plain english, if possible.

1) How can i encode it to see what is the content of this file properly?
2) After a change that i do on it, can i "decode" it back to binary?

Comment: This video will help you. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQN39X9oTi8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from what you wrote, you want to edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` from an APK file AFTER you built it, which is quite complicated. I suggest editing the source `AndroidManifest.xml` and then re-building the APK. If you can't do this then please do the following:

(1) First, download and install [Apktool](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/). It is a free Android tool for decompiling and recompiling apps quickly. It provides access to .class files, resources and XML's. [Here's a tutorial on how to install Apktool.](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/)

(2) Then you want to `decompile` your APK file ([tutorial](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/#decoding)).

(3) Edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

(4) Re-build the application ([tutorial](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/documentation/#building)).

(5) Finally, you will have your APK file but it will be mostly useless as it is un-signed. You can't install un-signed apps as you will get an error (it may be possible to force-install it using root or adb tho) and you can't publish them. To sign it you can check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually).

**IMPORTANT INFORMATION:** Your app will have to be signed with **the same certificate** with which it was signed the first time, otherwise it will be considered a **different app**. Not completely tho, you will have to un-install previous versions in order to install this one.
And yes, I know it's a very long and time-taking process but it is supposed to be, only if you have the source you should be able to edit the app.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the tool you are looking for is Apktool.
You need to use `--force-manifest` flag when you decompile to decode `AndroidmManifest.xml`.